# setDomainEnv.sh not such file of directory

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh, weblogic

I am building a bash script and want to call the setDomainEnv.sh inside the script but getting the error as

*"No such file or directory"*

.
Inside my script I have something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

. ./path/bin/setDomainEnv.sh
```

Do you have an idea how can I call the setDomainEnv.sh?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to make the path relative to where the script instead of the current working directory? https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/1032785

Comment: Where is setDomainEnv.sh?

Comment: setDomainEnv.sh is the weblogic domain script from $DOMAIN/bin

Comment: In my case the setDomainEnv.sh is available in the /u01/oracle/atg/domains/base_domain/bin path

Comment: So it's at `/u01/oracle/atg/domains/base_domain/bin/setDomainEnv.sh`? If so, `source /u01/oracle/atg/domains/base_domain/bin/setDomainEnv.sh` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash ./path/bin/setDomainEnv.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
When running the script setDomainEnv.sh I had to use only as below:

. /path/bin/setDomainEnv.sh

i.e, . space and then /path/bin/setDomainEnv.sh